How to fetch multiple images at once in Flask app?
I am writing a small Flask web app. One page displays 36 different images (very small ones, 20x20 pixels, all under 300 bytes) in a grid. These images are stored under static/images and are named clue0.png, clue1.png, ..., clue35.png.
I'm currently loading them with a loop in a Jinja file:
<div class="grid-container">
    {% for n in range(36) %}
    <div class="help-item">
        <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='images/clue' ~ n ~ '.png') }}">
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>

While this works, it feels very inefficient: each image has to be fetched individually, as seen in the logs:
127.0.0.1 - - [10/May/2024 16:38:01] "GET /static/images/clue0.png HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [10/May/2024 16:38:01] "GET /static/images/clue1.png HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [10/May/2024 16:38:01] "GET /static/images/clue3.png HTTP/1.1" 304 -
...
127.0.0.1 - - [10/May/2024 16:38:01] "GET /static/images/clue35.png HTTP/1.1" 304 -

Also, this means loading this page makes at least 36 requests at once to the website, which can be very problematic because most hosting solutions cap the number of calls to the website for their free tiers.
Is there a smarter way of doing this? Ideally I would like to make a single request fetching all images at once when the page is loaded.
I've thought about hosting the images on another website such as imgur but I'd rather keep everything inside the project codebase, and I feel like there is a better way to display several small images at once without making a lot of requests.

You cannot load multiple files with one request. So your variant is already a possibility. As an alternative to obtaining individual images, you can also combine all images into one and then extract them again after loading with an offscreen canvas in JavaScript. So basically like a sprite sheet or texture atlas known from game development.

It looks like using a sprite sheet was indeed the way to go, I've detailled my implementation in an answer, thank you!

Using an idea similar to what @Detlef suggested, I merged all images in a single sprite image. I then used this image as the background for all divs:
.help-item {
    background-image: url("{{ url_for('static', filename='images/clues.png') }}");
}

I used background-position and background-size to scale and display only the portion of the image I want for each div.
html:
<div class="grid-container">
    {% for n in range(36) %}
    <div class="help-item col{{ n % 6}} row{{n // 6}}"></div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>

css:
.help-item {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    image-rendering: pixelated;
    background-size: 600%;
}

.col0 {background-position-x: 0px;}
.col1 {background-position-x: -78px;}
...
.col5 {background-position-x: -390px;}

.row0 {background-position-y: 0px;}
.row1 {background-position-y: -78px;}
...
.row5 {background-position-y: -390px;}

The page now only requires one get request to get all images!
